# How can I connect several links in the input node?

Tags: pynodes

I need a slot to connect multiple links.
In the API is an attribute of links to the type of collections:

`links = self.inputs ['ListAttrs']. links`

`for link in links:`
...

How can I connect several links in the input node?

Comment: If your after some example code: https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/io_scene_fbx/cycles_shader_compat.py initialized as node tree, Im using for FBX importer to create node trees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links are created using `node_tree.links.new`:

> `new(input, output, verify_limits=True)`
>
> Add a node link to this node tree
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - `input` ([NodeSocket](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html#bpy.types.NodeSocket), (never None)) – The input socket
> - `output` ([NodeSocket](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.NodeSocket.html#bpy.types.NodeSocket), (never None)) – The output socket
> - `verify_limits` (boolean, (optional)) – Verify Limits, Remove existing links if connection limit is exceeded
>
> **Returns:** New node link
>   
>   **Return type:** [NodeLink](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.types.NodeLink.html#bpy.types.NodeLink)